# Spin structure, Intersection form and 2D TQFT

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-phase, spin-statistics

I am reading [this](http://www.theory.caltech.edu/~kapustin/fermionic_phases.pdf) (page 20) and watching this Anton Kaputins' [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlx1MXFDKbQ&t=374s) (33:24).

Here, he tried to explain **how to define a spin structure on a lattice** in a closed oriented (1+1)-D manifold $M$ (or at least the lattice analog of spin structure in Riemannian geometry.)

He mentioned that this was already pointed out by Atiyah in [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1971_4_4_1_47_0.pdf). And, on $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$, he introduced a non-degenerate bilinear form called **intersection form**:
$$
b(x,y):=\int_M\; x\cup y\; \in \mathbb{Z}_2,
$$
where $M$ is the spacetime 2-manifold.

This is the place where I got confused.

> **Question 1:** 
>   are $x,y$ the first Steifel-Whitney class of some bundle whose base space is M, namely $x,y\in H^1(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$?

If so, then (which we know this answer is no)

> **Question 1':**
>   Since we have $M$ being oriented, shouldn't its first Steifel-Whitney class vanishes (and hence the intersection form defined above also vanishes)?

I tried to look into [Atiyah's paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1971_4_4_1_47_0.pdf), but do not have enough power to understand it. Is there any plain language version of this (intersection, quadratic refinement, spin structure on lattice)?

References will be largely appreciated.

Comment: I think the $x$, $y$ are any cohomology classes, not necessarily Stiefel-Whitney,